# Why pthread_getname_np() fails in the thread in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, pthreads

This is the snippet of the code. I am able to set the name of thread. However, I get an error while retrieving the name of the thread. Please help.

```
void *Thread_Function_A(void *thread_arg)
{

  char buf[7];

  int rc;  

  pthread_t self;

  self = pthread_self ();


  rc = pthread_getname_np(self, buf,7);

  if ( rc != 0 )
  cout<<"Failed getting the name"<<endl;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rc;
   pid_t thread_pid_val = getpid();
   thread_1.create_thread((thread_1.get_thread_id()), NULL,Thread_Function_A,&thread_pid_val);
   thread_2.create_thread((thread_2.get_thread_id()), NULL,Thread_Function_A,&thread_pid_val);
   rc = pthread_setname_np(*(thread_1.get_thread_id()), "Thread_A");
   if( rc != 0)
   {
     cout<<"Setting name for thread A failed"<<endl; 
   }
   rc = pthread_setname_np(*(thread_2.get_thread_id()), "Thread_B");
   if( rc != 0)
   {
     cout<<"Setting name for thread B failed"<<endl; 
   }
   pthread_join( *(thread_1.get_thread_id()), NULL);
   pthread_join( *(thread_2.get_thread_id()), NULL);

   return  0;   
}
```

output : -

```
$./thread_basic.out 
Failed getting the nameFailed getting the name

The name of thread is The name of thread is
```

The strerror says - Numerical result out of range
error =34

Added now complete code. Here, I don't get the right name set. Instead, it retrieves the name of the program.

```
void *Thread_Function_A(void *thread_arg)
{

  char name[300];
  char buf[200];

  int rc;  
  char message[100];

  FILE *fp;

  pthread_t self;

  self = pthread_self ();


  rc = pthread_getname_np(self, buf,200);

  if ( rc != 0 )
  {
    cout<<"Failed getting the name"<<endl;
    cerr<<"Pthread get name error ="<<rc<< " " << strerror(rc) << endl;  
  }

  sprintf(name,"log_%s.txt",buf);

  cout<<"The name of thread is "<<buf<<endl;

  fp = fopen(name,"w+");

  for( int i = 1; i<=5; i++)
  {
    sprintf(message,"The thread id is %d  and value of i is %d",pthread_self(),i);

    fprintf(fp,"%s\n", message);
    fflush(fp);
    /** local variable will not be shared actually**/
    /** each thread should execute the loop for 5 **/
    /** total prints should be 10 **/

  }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rc;
   pthread_t threadA, threadB;
   pid_t thread_pid_val = getpid();
   thread_1.create_thread(&threadA, NULL,Thread_Function_A,&thread_pid_val);
   thread_1.set_thread_id(threadA);
   rc = pthread_setname_np(threadA, "Thread_A");
   if( rc != 0)
   {
     cout<<"Setting name for thread A failed"<<endl; 
   }

   thread_2.create_thread(&threadB, NULL,Thread_Function_A,&thread_pid_val);
   thread_2.set_thread_id(threadB);
   rc = pthread_setname_np(threadB, "Thread_B");
   if( rc != 0)
   {
     cout<<"Setting name for thread B failed"<<endl; 
   }
   pthread_join( threadA, NULL);
   pthread_join( threadB, NULL);

   return  0;   
}
```

The output is the following.

```
]$ ./thread_basic.out 
The name of thread is thread_basic.ou
The name of thread is Thread_B
```

Comment: If you read the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) you will see that the function returns the error number (instead of setting it in `errno`), you might want to print that (or it printable string with [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror)).

Comment: Numerical result out of range is the error.

Comment: Read the manual page I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: Also, there is a race condition here: what, if the threads reach the call to `pthread_getname_np` before the starting thread had a chance to assign the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the race condition, which won't make your call fail but may not return what you want, this is why the call fails.

`man 3 pthread_getname_np`

> The pthread_getname_np() function can be used to retrieve the name of the thread.  The thread argument specifies the thread whose name is to be retrieved.  The buffer name is used to return the thread name; len specifies the number of bytes available in name.  **The buffer  specified by name should be at least 16 characters in length.**  The returned thread name in the output buffer will be null terminated.

```
char buf[7];
```

is going to fail.

Comment: I was able to correct it by my own.  However, there is a problem with setting the name. It doesn't set the name. I am going to write the scenario again.

Comment: It doesn't set the name because your thread will be over and done before you ever get to set the name in main.  That's the race condition several people have mentioned.

Comment: For experimenting?  Just put some kind of delay (e.g. sleep) in the thread so it lives long enough to get the name set.  For real life, the normal set of synchronization methods - mutexes, condvars, semaphores, etc., or just pass the thread name in as a variable and have the thread name itself.

Comment: mutex where? I am setting the name in the main function. I am reading the name inside the thread. How can I make the setting of name to occur before I read it. I don't want to use sleep.

Comment: main acquires the lock, starts the thread, sets the name, unlocks.  Thread is started but immediately blocks on lock until main has set the name and gives up the lock.

Comment: It worked.!! I am unlocking mutex before pthread_join in the main(). Hope it is right.

Comment: Remember to unlock it in the thread as soon as it acquires too.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mix of C and C++ features which you should avoid, and with parts of code that we can't verify, e.g your method `get_thread_id`. But the problem of your code is obvious, you are trying to obtain the the names of the threads far too early: your `main` has not the slightest chance to place the names before the threads are already terminated.

Also, your thread function is not correct, and any compiler with a minimum level of warning should have told you. A function with a non-`void` return type needs a `return` statement. In C this would only lead to undefined behavior if you'd use the return value of the function, which you can't know since it is the thread library which calls your function.

Comment: what is the way to fix this race condition?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI, for anything of that kind the combination of mutex and condition variable is your friend. That is *the* way in POSIX to coordiante threads that is guaranteed to work everywhere.

Comment: I am setting the name in the main(), and reading it inside the thread routine. How to synchronise these events?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI, I have already answered that question. With a combination of mutex and condition variable. If you don't know what that means, it is time to document yourself, this is basic knowledge if you are programming with POSIX threads.

Comment: yup, I got it. I could make it work by myself. I got that there is a race condition because pthread_create will create a thread and the thread routine will start. However, the thread name is created later. A lock will make sure that the thread routine doesn't run until and unless the setname is done. In the thread routine just lock and unlock immediately.